# The current path, index.php, didn’t match any of these

Tags: django

**

Good day, please am new to Django and am facing some challenges
which have tried to resolve but am not yet resolve please i need
your help.

**

**the error are below**

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://mydomain/pages/index.php**
```

*Using the URLconf defined in dcitygate.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:*

```
admin/
[name='index']
blog/ [name='blog']
audio_messages/ [name='audio_messages']
imgc/ [name='imgc']
imgc/<int:id> [name='imgc_detail']
tsc/ [name='tsc']
tsc/<int:id> [name='tsc_detail']
word_prayer/ [name='word_prayer']
word_prayer/<int:id> [name='word_prayer_detail']
video_messages/ [name='video_messages']
contact_us/ [name='contact_us']
couple_meeting/ [name='couple_meeting']
kcc/ [name='kcc']
kcc/<int:id> [name='kcc_detail']
pages/streaming/ [name='streaming']
watchlive/ [name='watchlive']
<int:id> [name='audio_streaming_detail']
listenlive/ [name='listenlive']
blogs/
audio_msg/
^media/(?P<path>.*)$'''
*The current path, index.php, didn’t match any of these*
```

**my Project.url**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/',admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('blogs/', include('blogs.urls')),
    path('audio_msg/', include('audio_msg.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**MyApp.url**

```
 from django.urls import path, re_path
 from django.conf.urls import url


from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('blog/',views.blog, name='blog'),
path('audio_messages/', views.audio_messages, name='audio_messages'),
path('imgc/', views.imgc, name='imgc'),
path('imgc/<int:id>', views.imgc_detail, name='imgc_detail'),
path('tsc/', views.tsc, name='tsc'),
path('tsc/<int:id>', views.tsc_detail, name='tsc_detail'),
path('word_prayer/', views.word_prayer, name='word_prayer'),
path('word_prayer/<int:id>', views.word_prayer_detail, name='word_prayer_detail'),
path('video_messages/', views.video_messages, name='video_messages'),
path('contact_us/', views.contact_us, name='contact_us'),
path('couple_meeting/', views.couple_meeting, name='couple_meeting'),
path('kcc/', views.kcc, name='kcc'),
path('kcc/<int:id>', views.kcc_detail, name='kcc_detail'),
path('pages/streaming/', views.streaming, name='streaming'),
path('watchlive/', views.watchlive, name='watchlive'),
path('<int:id>', views.audio_streaming_detail, name='audio_streaming_detail'),
path('listenlive/', views.listenlive, name='listenlive'),
```

]

**my view**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from blogs.models import Blog
from audio_msg.models import Audio_msg
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger, Paginator
```

**# Create your views here.**

```
def index(request):
    blog_data = Blog.objects.order_by('-created_date')
    audio_data = Audio_msg.objects.order_by('-created_date')
    data = {
    'blog_data': blog_data,
    'audio_data': audio_data,
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/home.html', data)


def blog(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/blog.html')


def audio_messages(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/audio_messages.html')

def imgc(request):
    blog_data = Blog.objects.order_by('-created_date').filter(category='IMGC')
    paginator = Paginator(blog_data, 9)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    paged_blog = paginator.get_page(page)
    data = {
    'blog_data': paged_blog,
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/imgc.html', data)

def imgc_detail(request, id):
    blog_detail = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=id)
    data = {
    'blog_detail': blog_detail,
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/imgc_detail.html', data)

def tsc(request):
    blog_data = Blog.objects.order_by('-created_date').filter(category='TSC')

    paginator = Paginator(blog_data, 9)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    paged_blog = paginator.get_page(page)
    data = {
    'blog_data': paged_blog,
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/tsc.html', data)

def tsc_detail(request, id):
    blog_detail = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=id)
    data = {
    'blog_detail': blog_detail,
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/tsc_detail.html', data)

def word_prayer(request):
    blog_data = Blog.objects.order_by('-created_date').filter(category='WAP')
    paginator = Paginator(blog_data, 9)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    paged_blog = paginator.get_page(page)
 
    data = {
    'blog_data': paged_blog,
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/word_prayer.html', data)

def word_prayer_detail(request, id):
    blog_detail = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=id)
    data = {
    'blog_detail': blog_detail,
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/word_prayer_detail.html', data)

def video_messages(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/video_messages.html')


def audio_messages(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/audio_messages.html')


def contact_us(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/contact_us.html')

def couple_meeting(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/couple_meeting.html')

def kcc(request):
    blog_data = Blog.objects.order_by('-created_date').filter(category='KCC')
    data = {
    'blog_data': blog_data,
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/kcc.html', data)

def kcc_detail(request, id):
    blog_detail = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=id)
    data = {
    'blog_detail': blog_detail,
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/kcc_detail.html', data)

def streaming(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/streaming.html')

def watchlive(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/watchlive.html')

def listenlive(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/listenlive.html')

def audio_msg(request):
    audio_data = Audio_msg.objects.order_by('-created_date')

    data = {
    'audio_data': audio_data,

    }
    return render(request, 'pages/audio_msg.html', data)

def audio_streaming_detail(request, id):
    audio_data = get_object_or_404(Audio_msg, pk=id)
    data = {
    'audio_data': audio_data,
    }
    **return render(request, 'pages/audio_streaming_detail.html', data)
```

please help**

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any `pages/index.php` anywhere, and you shouldn't use `.php` on Django projects, it's not PHP

If you're trying to get to: `path('', views.index, name='index')` just try http://127.0.0.1:8000/

If you are trying to get to another view, what view?- ti should be in a urls.py

Comment: Thank you for coming to my rescue. i dont have any index.php on my project. please help

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for this platform and everyone that have contributed to this question.
my solution to the problem was removing the default redirect code in .htaccess and use this code below.

```
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN
PassengerAppRoot "/home2/thecity2/church-project"
PassengerBaseURI "/"
PassengerPython "/home2/thecity2/virtualenv/church-project/3.9/bin/python"
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION BEGIN
<IfModule Litespeed>
</IfModule>
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION END
```

Comment: This is the default code i met        

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php56” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56___lsphp .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>